# Storybook / Show state dump in panel

Tags: reactjs, storybook, storybook-addon

I'd like to show the *dump* of my react component's state in a storybook panel.

Is there a storybook plugin for this purpose?

```
export default () => {
  const [a] = useMyHook();

  /** ---> **/ showDumpInStorybookPanel(a); /** <--- **/ 

  return (
    <Comp prop={prop} />
  );
};
```